# Why is my SSL certificate tied to my domain provider(Doteasy)?

Tags: ssl, https, cpanel

I recently bought an SSL certificate for my website but when I try connecting with HTTPS it gives me this message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqi0D.png)

What it seems to be doing is tying my certificate to my domain name provider(doteasy.com) instead of my actual website domain. Any help is appreciated!

(edit: direct image link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqi0D.png

edit2:
This is a screenshot of the error message that shows up when I test the page on whynopadlock.com
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4BTX.png)
Alternate link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4BTX.png

Comment: yo, for some reason image is invalid or inaccessible, could you leave a link to an image on imgur or any other image hosting?

Comment: If you bought a certificate for another domain, then either you didn't install it correctly of your webserver is showing another one (ie. the one for doteasy.com).

Comment: @suprovsky Thanks for the heads up, I edited the post and added a direct link

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I bought it for my main site, and when the installation finishes it says that it's available on my domain, but when I go to the website to test it, it fails

Comment: That may be so, but you don't provide any information that would allow someone to help you.

Comment: Usually when you get a paid certificate, you have to serve a chain file (containing CA certificate and your domain certificate. Are you sure you're using a correct file in a webserver settings?

Comment: In the CPanel, "You will also see your secured website added to the Manage Installed SSL Websites table."   Do you?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yeah, it shows up on the table there with my website under the FQDN's column

Comment: Anything else in that table?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Nope, just that one

Comment: You followed these steps carefully?  https://www.doteasy.com/cpanel-hosting-features/installing-a-pre-existing-third-party-ssl-certificate

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yeah that's the one I used initially to install it, I just double checked and I followed the steps

Comment: Normally, you would have to restart the Apache server.  Is that part of the installation process?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I didn't see anything on the installation process about a restart, I tried republishing the page, but still doesnt work

Comment: Surely, the CPanel has an option to restart your webserver?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Ive been looking for a little, but I cant seem to find any options to restart

Comment: Neither did I, sorry.  If you're sure you clicked "install", you'll have to ask the people of doteasy themselves.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Alright, I'll submit a request, thank you!!

Comment: Are you accessing your webserver via the IP or FQDN? If you have shared hosting then chances are they will require SNI support (Which is why if you access it over IP it will take you to the hosting provider's page and not your website)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have accidentally installed the intermediate (chain cert) as your entity (domain) certificate. In the case of Apache you would normally install the entity certificate which contains your domain name as well as the intermediate certificate.

On other platforms you sometimes have multiple certificates combined into one file and the order of those is detailed here: https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm

Answer (score 0):

So I sent in a support request to doteasy, and it turns out the issue was something with website.com sitebuilder. Website.com runs on a different server than cPanel, so the only way to enable SSL is to buy Website.com's SSL cert(which is way more expensive than what I bought) or Doteasy's Business plan. I'm working on building a new webpage on Wordpress now because I needed a new one anyways and so that I can use the SSL cert that I bought.
Thanks for the help everyone!